# Why the Time is missing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have code below:

```
declare
  v_rst varchar2(200);

  cursor c_cur is
    select sysdate from dual;
begin

  open c_cur;
  fetch c_cur
    into v_rst;
  close c_cur;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_rst);

end;
```

the output result for it is `23-DEC-14`

When I run below query, the result is `12/23/2014 11:21:06 AM`:

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

I do not know why the `TIME` part is gone when I run the first code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The time is not "gone".  That format is just the default. You need to set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the default value:

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS';
```

or whatever format your want.

Or, change your query to format the date field using the `to_char` function

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS') from dual;
```

See the format model [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211).